# Is there a "method_missing" for rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake, method-missing

If my Rakefile does not find a task with a particular name, I'd like `rake` to instead create a new task by that name according to certain rules, if a file with the missing task name exists. But if it doesn't, I want to fall back to the default ("Don't know how to build task 'foo'!").

In short, is there a `method_missing` for Rake?

Comment: I'd love to know how to do this if that's possible. I don't think `method_missing` is really the right thing to look for, though. Rake is really looking up names, not methods, for tasks.

It would be more appropriate if there were something like a `task_missing` hook that you could override, but a cursory inspection of the code doesn't show anything like that.

Answer (score 12):

I haven't tried it, but a quick search revealed [this](http://snippets.dzone.com/posts/show/2337).

> If you define a rule with an empty
>   string, you can catch any task that
>   hasn’t been defined elsewhere. This
>   makes it easy to dynamically create
>   rake tasks. Essentially, this is
>   method_missing for rake!
>
> ```
> rule "" do |t|
>   t.name 
>   # ... do something with the name of the task  
> end
> ```

Comment: This works great. Except that I have no access to anything in the /lib folder from a rule.